# Jest testing React component using Electron-Remote in ElectronJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, electron, jestjs

I'm currently developing an ElectronJS application using React for the UI. In some React components I'm using nodeJS packages via Electron remote, so I import packages from the main process into the renderer process. Looks like this:

main.js

```
global.moment = moment;
```

Component.js

```
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
const moment = remote.getGlobal('moment');
```

Everything is working fine until I've started to implement unit testing with Jest.

I've created the first following test case:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});
```

Running this test gives me the following output:

```
TypeError: window.require is not a function
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem, maybe someone has an idea how to fix this. Maybe somebody have an idea how to setup unit tests for React in Electron which allows to use nodeJS packages in the React component.

I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in src/setupTest.js

`window.require = require;`

reference: [Jest Testing Electron/React Component using window.require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927086/jest-testing-electron-react-component-using-window-require)