# Jest Testing Electron/React Component using window.require

Tags: reactjs, electron, jestjs

I'm currently creating an Electron application that uses React to create the interface. In order to get access the fs, I have been using:

```
const fs = window.require('fs');
```

Which works fine when in an Electron window.

The issue is that when I write jest tests for any components that use the window.require('fs'), I get the following error when running the test.

```
TypeError: window.require is not a function
```

I have looked through the documentation for Jest and it seems the solution is to generate a mock of window using a manual mock (see "Mocking methods which are not implemented in JSDOM" at https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks). However, when I tried to mock window.require by adding at the top of my test file

```
window.require = jest.fn();
```

I still get the same TypeError.

I'm very new to create Jest mocks so any help with this would be much appreciated.

My current test file (Component.test.js) looks like

```
window.require = jest.fn();

import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Component from '../index';

describe('Testing', () => {
    it('Component renders correctly', () => {
        const component = renderer.create(<Component />);
        let tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Comment: disclaimer: I haven't done a lot with Electron...having said that, it looks like they call `require('fs')` directly in [the sample apps](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos/blob/2a8c1f46b582b2762c2cf0afc7559082726255b5/renderer-process/media/desktop-capturer.js#L3), is there a reason to call `window.require` instead of just `require`?

Comment: This GitHub issue (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300) goes into why `window.require` is needed over `require`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once faced this issue and below was what solved it for me:

I had to leverage on the module `react-app-rewired`. this module Tweaks the webpack config(s), even for those using `create-react-app(CRA)` without using 'eject' and without creating a fork of the react-scripts.

all you need is to add a `config-overrides.js` file in the root of your project, and populate it with the snippet below:

```js
module.exports = function override (config) {
  config.target = 'electron-renderer'
  return config;
}
```

then you proceed to your `package.json` and replace your start script with

`"start": "react-app-rewired start"` . and you are done. you can thereafter rebuild and run your test script without getting the `window.require is not a function` error.

I hope I have been able to help.

cheers!

Comment: originally overlooked this as 'cmon..not another dependency' but this (or something like craco or rescripts..though react-app-rewired has the best npm stats as of today) is really a clean way to get around this.  Found this in another thread after seeing this one.  This should be accepted as the answer IMO

Comment: Can I use this is I didn't use Create-React-App though? I'm facing a really similar issue but I built my own Webpack, so it doesn't use CRA's webpack.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line at the beginning of your test (or in a [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) setup file):

```
window.require = require;
```

**Details**

`electron` supplies `window.require` but it isn't defined when running unit tests with `Jest`.

By default `Jest` provides a browser-like environment using `jsdom` that includes a `window` object.

The above line mocks `window.require` by setting it equal to the current value of `require`.

Comment: I tried to put ``window.require = require;`` at the top of the test.js file and I still get the ``window.require is not a function`` error. I also tried to enable setupFilesAfterEnv but since I am using Jest through create-react-app, setupFilesAfterEnv is not a configurable option (according to the console print-out I got when I tried to enable it in package.json)

Comment: huh, interesting.  there have been a couple of other people having trouble adding things to `window` or `global`.  I haven't been able to reproduce the issues.  Do you have a simple repo that demonstrates the problem?  I'd be really interested in seeing it happen and trying to figure out why it's happening.  @DLee

Comment: This works for me. I've added `window.require = require;`  to setupTests.js

Comment: (Putting it at beginning of a test file didn't work for me.)

Comment: Adding ```window.require = require``` to my setupTests.js worked for me!! I've been stuck on this for hours - thanks @Harry!